# How to match complex unknown patterns in perl, when the pattern is in a variable?

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

There is a config file, that contains patterns, provided by user. Basically the pattern could be anything, a combination of alphabets,numbers, spaces, braces that too not necessarily closed, and special characters.
Patterns For Example: `<Error my (error** fail& 345% ?+[+?>`

I am very new to perl and struggling to handle this.

my piece of code:

```
for (<FH>) {
    for ( my $j = 0 ; $j < $num_pat ; $j = $j + 1 ) {
        print "This is the pattern : $pat_array[$j] \n";
        if ( $_ =~ m/'$pat_array[$j]'/ ) {
            print "$_ : match found for $pat_array[$j] \n";
            #print "KPI for the pattern is : $kpi_array[$match] : array style \n";
            $match_count[$j] = ( $match_count[$j] + 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Pattern array has multiple patterns.
I am trying to find matches using : if **($_ =~ m/'$pat_array[$j]'/)**
It works for simple patterns, but not for the ones in example.

Please help me to proceed further.

Comment: To be able to give a meaningful answer as to why your pattern doesn't match, we'd need some example data, and then we might be able to tell you. I'd say probably because you're quoting `$pat_array[$j]` but it might be cause you're not escaping meta characters properly.

Comment: The example you've given is definitely not a valid regex - `**` is definitely not allowed without being escaped

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear because what you have there is not a "complex unknown regex pattern", it's simply not a valid regex. It's not clear what you're trying to do with this or what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks everyone. My bad, I used the term regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the special characters.
See [perldoc -f quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

You can also use the shorthand `\Q$variable\E` syntax like that:

```
if ($string =~ m/\Q$pattern\E/) { ... }
```

Any special char will be matched literally now.

Comment: Or if you're just looking for a substring, `index`.

Comment: Thank you so much tinita :)